# ASP.NET MVC view return empty object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, binding

I have the following code, but it return me an empty `FormationDTO` object, did I do anything wrong?
I don't understand why it can't properly bind `FormationFormViewModel`'s `FormationDTO` to the action parameter `FormationDTO`, it worked in others controllers.

**FormationsController**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Save(FormationDTO formation)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid){
        return View("FormationForm", new FormationFormViewModel { FormationDTO = formation, Categories = GetCategories() });
    }
    else{
        // DO THE STUFF
    }

}
```

**FormationForm.cshtml**

```
@model BSS_IT_Education.Models.FormationFormViewModel

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Formation";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Formations"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FormationDTO.Id)

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FormationDTO.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FormationDTO.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Entrez le nom de la formation..." } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FormationDTO.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        // BUNCH OF OTHERS FORM-GROUPS

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">@((Model.FormationDTO.Id == 0) ? "Sauvegarder  " : "Modifier")</button>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the code correctly. It looks like you should be passing `FormationFormViewModel` to the controller action. Not `FormationDTO`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand why this is not binding this way.  
I did the exact same thing on another controller (using viewmodel containing multiple objects and retrieving one of the objects in the POST action) and It worked just nice.

Comment: @ArmelMercier When, in a view, you have a form and do `model => model.//whatever`, it is binding and setting the view's model (whatever is passed into that view). So when you submit the form, you are submitting THAT model to the action.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the generated HTML on the page.  I'm guessing the `name` attributes on your input elements will look something like `formationDTO.name`, because your ViewModel is a `FormationFormViewModel`.  But the ModelBinder on the backend is going to look for just a property `name`, because you are trying to build a `FormationDTO`.

You may need to manually create those input elements, or use a child action to get the correct ViewModel to a view that lets you use the razor @Html helpers to build the correct elements.

Or, the easier option is to make your controller action accept a `FormationFormViewModel`, then the ModelBinder should correctly build out the properties of the `FormationDTO` you want.